# The intuition behind that the cyclic submodule C generated by A is given by a specific formula.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Why the cyclic submodule C generated by A  is given by the given formula, why there is addition and why we include an n $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$, what is the intuition behind this form, could anyone explain for me please?

[image]

Comment: ii) is redundant statement as i) is the meat part. You have natural morphism for $1\in Z$ and you can define $Z\to R$ by sending $1\in 1_R$. The morphism is simply adding $1_R$. You do not necessarily have $Z\subset R$ as a subring but its image is always sitting inside. It is basically saying you can add $a$ like $a+a+a+\dots+a$ integer times as well.

Comment: @user45765  but I am asking about (ii)

Comment: How is cyclic module defined in your book if not as the set $Ra$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part ii. Put $C'=\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. The claim that $C'=C$ is a subject of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468835/a-difficulty-in-proving-that-a-cyclic-submodule-has-a-specified-formula) answered question. Clearly, that $Ra=\{ra +0a \mid r\in R\}\subset C’$. On the other hand, if $R$ has an identity $e$ and $C$ is [unitary](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Unitary_module) then $eb=b$ for each $r\in C$. 
Thus for each $r\in R$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $$ra+na=ra+nea=(r+ne)a\in Ra,$$ so $C\subset Ra$.

Comment: I think in the third line for each $b \in C.$.... right?