# A difficulty in proving that a cyclic submodule has a specified formula.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ an $R$-module, $a \in A$. Then the cyclic submodule $C$ generated by $a$ is $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Here I am using the definition of a cyclic submodule as being the intersection of all submodules of $A$ containing the element $a$.

But I do not know how to prove the following direction:
$$\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \bigcap_{\overset{\text{$F$ s.m. A}}{F \,\ni\, a}} F.$$

I know that the l.h.s contains a because $(ra + na) = (r + n)a$, and if we take r=n=1 then a is in the l.h.s and by definition of the r.h.s a is in it. but does this help in what we want to prove?

Could anyone help me please?

thanks!

Comment: Use the definition of a module to prove that any module that contains $a$ must contain any $ra+na$, so your set is contained in the intersection. And, of course, prove that the described set is indeed a module, so that the your set contains the intersection.

Comment: could u please say more details about your first statement ?@Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $C’=\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $F$ be any $R$-submodule of $A$ containing $a$. Since $rF\subset F$ for any $r\in R$, $ra\in F$. Next, if $x,y\in F$ then $x+y$ and $x-y\in F$ too. This implies that $0=a-a\in F$ and inductively implies that $na\in F$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z$. The above implies that $ra+na\in F$ for any $r\in R$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$, so $C’\subset F$.